# Branch wise Division in CRM module in Openerp

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

For a company there can be different branches across the country. In Openerp,in  CRM module Can i filter the Leads by Branches(here filter should be branch name) of that company.Thanks in advance.
My Code

lead.py

```
'branch_name':fields.selection([('Ahmedabad','Ahmedabad'),('Bangalore','Bangalore'),('Chennai','Chennai'),('Hyderabad','Hyderabad'),('Koltata','Koltata'),('Mumbai','Mumbai'),('NewDelhi','New Delhi'),('Pune','Pune')],'Branch'),
```

lead_view.xml

```
<record id="lead_view_crm_case_leads_filter" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">CRM - Leads Search</field>
    <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.view_crm_case_leads_filter" />
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <search string="Search Leads">
          <field name="branch_name" filter_domain="[('branch_name','ilike',self)]"/>
        </search>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: What are you asking? did you know? what a idiot question

Answer (score 0):

added and new field branch in crm.lead. inherit search view added this field in filter

it will help you

Comment: I have done the same but i couldn't find filter option.Can u please tell me where can i get the filter option

Comment: @ Kala I have added a Branch as new field. Can you please tell me where can i add branch into filter

Comment: you have to inherit this view view_crm_case_leads_filter and added field here

Comment: I have edited my question.I have added my code.Can you please say me where did i go wrong.Please help me